# Typescript refer to the same type as the super method

Tags: typescript

Let's say I'm using an external library that provides the following class:

```
Class A {
  ...overloads types
  doSomething(param, params) {

  }
}
```

I want to override the `super` method and provide my implementation, but I want to **keep the types of the original**. (including the overloads)

```
Class B extends A {
   doSomething(param, params) {
     // ...some logic
     super.doSomething(); 
   }
}
```

There is a way to do this with Typescript?

Answer (score 2):

Should work fine exactly how you described it:

```
class A {
  test() {
    return 'from class A';
  }
}

class B extends A {
  test() {
    return super.test() + ' and from class B';
  }
}
```

you can play with it here on the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20test()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20'from%20class%20A'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20test()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20super.test()%20%2B%20'%20and%20from%20class%20B'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20button%20%3D%20document.createElement('button')%3B%0D%0Abutton.textContent%20%3D%20new%20B().test()%3B%0D%0Adocument.body.appendChild(button)%3B)

To keep the args:

```
class A {
  test(a: number) {
    return `from class A ${a}`;
  }
}

class B extends A {
  test: A['test'] = (...args) => {
    return super.test(...args) + ' and from class B';
  }
}
```

and if you want it on the prototype:

```
class A {
  test(param: number | string): void {
    console.log(param);
  }
}

type ArgumentsType<T> = T extends (...args: infer A) => any ? A : never;

class B extends A {
  test(...args: ArgumentsType<A['test']>): ReturnType<A['test']> {
    return super.test(...args);
  }
}
```

Comment: The arrow function solution is not bad, but you should keep in mind that since arrow functions need to capture `this` and thus a new instance of the function must be created for each object instance. This might matter in certain performance critical scenarios.

Comment: Your example is not on the prototype.

Comment: @undefined added an example with the function on the prototype

Comment: @AndreiTătar it yells when using with overloads.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript does not infer parameter types based on the base type. The way things go is that the class is typed independently and then checked for inconsistencies with the base class. This also means there is no way to keep the overloads from the base class.

One way you could reduce the syntax is to assign to the prototype of `B`

```
class A {
    doSomething(param: number, params: number)
    doSomething(param: string, params: string)
    doSomething(param: number | string, params: number | string) {
        alert ("A")
    }
}

class B extends A {

}

B.prototype.doSomething = function doSomething(this: B, param, params) {
    alert("B");
    A.prototype.doSomething.call(this, arguments);
} 

new A().doSomething(0, 0)
new B().doSomething(0,0)
```

This way the types of the parameters are inferred and if you have an explicit annotation for `this` it will be typed appropriately inside the function. Only drawback is you have to use a rather large syntax to issue the super call

Comment: It's unfortunate. There is no other way to do it normally? If the author exposes an interface or something like that?

Comment: @undefined As far as I know there is no other way o do it without repeating all the overloads

Comment: It's very weird that I can declare the type of a method that exists on the prototype.

Comment: @undefined not sure what you mean. You can assign methods on the prototype. This is in fact when compiling to ES5 this is what TS itself does.

Comment: What I mean is why I can't infer methods that are on the prototype like the arrow function style doSomething: A["doSomething"]. (in a class style-like)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax would be super awkward and you are no longer will be leveraging prototype, but rather defining the method in the constructor which might have performance implications but this works:

```
class A {
    doSomething(param: number): void
    doSomething(param: string): void
    doSomething(param: number | string): void {

    }
}

class B extends A {
    doSomething: A["doSomething"] = () => {
        A.prototype.doSomething.call(this)
    }
}

const b = new B();

b.doSomething(42) // ok
b.doSomething("foo") // ok
b.doSomething(false) // error
```